# LWC tree grid not rendering the data

Tags: javascript, salesforce, treeview, apex, lwc

[tempdata in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XztOL.png)Hi iam creating an lwc component for tree grid view i have get the data from my controller but it is not rendering into the user interface.

My js code

```
import { LightningElement, track,wire,api} from 'lwc';
import getDomainsList from "@salesforce/apex/DataDomainTreeViewController.getDomainsList";

export default class Datadomaintreeview extends LightningElement {
dataDomainsval;
error;
@track expandedRows = [];
@track gridColumns = [{
    type:'url',
    fieldName:'name',
    label:'Data Domain Name',
    typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'name' }, target: '_blank'}
}];


@track gridData;
@track gridData2;


connectedCallback(){
    //var tempDomains = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{"Id":"a1b04000000tEQgAAM","Name":"Shared Services","Data_Domains__r":[{"Parent_Data_Domain__c":"a1b04000000tEQgAAM","Id":"a1b04000000tERPAA2","Name":"Human Resources","Data_Domains__r":[{"Parent_Data_Domain__c":"a1b04000000tERPAA2","Id":"a1b04000000tERyAAM","Name":"Employee Data"}]},{"Parent_Data_Domain__c":"a1b04000000tEQgAAM","Id":"a1b04000000tER1AAM","Name":"Manufacturing"},{"Parent_Data_Domain__c":"a1b04000000tEQgAAM","Id":"a1b04000000tEQnAAM","Name":"Finance"},{"Parent_Data_Domain__c":"a1b04000000tEQgAAM","Id":"a1b04000000tEQUAA2","Name":"Supply Chain"}]}]));
    getDomainsList().then(result =>{
        var tempDomains = [];
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            if(result[i]?.Parent_Data_Domain__c == undefined){
                console.log('this is the root list',result[i]);
               tempDomains = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[i]));
               var arr = [];
               for(let j in tempDomains){
                console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>',tempDomains);
                         console.log('this is the result',result);
                    var newDomain = tempDomains.Data_Domains__r;
                    delete tempDomains.Data_Domains__r;
                    if(newDomain){
                        for(let x in newDomain){
                            console.log('every new domain value',newDomain[x]);
                            tempDomains._children = newDomain[x];
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        tempDomains = '['+JSON.stringify(tempDomains)+']';
        console.log('temp json static data',this.data2);
        console.log('my dasta',tempDomains);
        console.log('type of both STAT',JSON.stringify(this.data2));
        console.log('type of both SDYN',JSON.stringify(tempDomains));
        // var obj = JSON.parse(json.stringify(tempDomains));
        // console.log('temp data',obj);
        this.gridData= tempDomains;
    })
     
}}
```

My html code

```
<template>
<lightning-card title = "Data Domains">
    <lightning-tree-grid
    columns = {gridColumns}
    max-column-width="1500"
    data={gridData}
    key-field="name"
    hide-checkbox-column></lightning-tree-grid>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

My handler class code

```
public class DataDomainTreeViewController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Data_Domain__c> getDomainsList(){
    List<Data_Domain__c> domainList = [SELECT id,Name,Parent_Data_Domain__c,(SELECT ID,Name FROM Data_Domains__r) FROM Data_Domain__c];
    if(!domainList.isEmpty()){
        return domainList;
    }
    return null;
    
}}
```

i need to show the tree view which is the top most parent on the top and its child in tree view can anyone help me on this
[tree view is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNxiB.png)

Answer (score 0):

```js
...
tempDomains = '['+JSON.stringify(tempDomains)+']';
this.gridData= tempDomains;
```

You are passing a string value to `gridData`.
Take a look at the [documentation example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/example), specifically the `sampleData.js` file. `data` should be a list of objects, by the looks of your code you are passing a string to it.

Comment: thanks for the reply i tried `tempDomains = '['+JSON.stringify(tempDomains)+']';` removing this line that is converting to string format but still the issue is not resolved

Comment: Can you provide an example of how your `gridData` (or `tempDomains`) looks? You can censor data, I am interested in the structure

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XztOL.png]tempData  is printing in the console like this

Comment: Could you try making it an array instead of an object? `gridData = [ tempDomains ]`. Make sure `_children` is an array as well. Again I would like to point out the [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/example)